# Problems specifying contentCss outside CKEditor.basepath

Tags: ckeditor, vignette

We are trying to use `CKEditor` as a `Widget` for `Vignette`, when we try to specify a `content css outside the environment of CKEditor` such as:

```
"CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = 'http://lvhost:27110/CKEditorbk/my.css';"
```

doesn't work, but when we specify a content css included in the war where we have our deployment of ckeditor such as:

```
CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = 'http://lvhost:27110/CKEditor/ckeditor/my.css';
```

It's working as we expected. `Isn't possible to specify a css outside "CKEditor.basepath"?`

Answer (score 1):

In fact you can't because CKEditor path scope is anything within a folder named `ckeditor`.

However you could have your custom css outside the CKeditor's ckeditor by replicating the same folder structure, that is `/js/CUSTOM_CKEDITOR/ckeditor`. I've done so when I wrote a plugin for CKeditor.

I have a custom css at `/js/CUSTOM_CKEDITOR/ckeditor/plugins/my_plugin/css/custom.css`. And in my `/js/CUSTOM_CKEDITOR/ckeditor/config.js` I used:

`CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = CKEDITOR.plugins.getPath( 'my_plugin' ) + 'css/custom.css';`

Works sweet :)